# Align image pairs with high accuracy

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have series of photos with different view of almost flat object.
One part of object depends on view and I want to detect it.
So I detect keypoints, find matches and wrap photos, they looks almost aligned after that but because object almost flat (not ideally) there some distortion.

I have tried to detect more keypoints on wrapped pairs to get dense matches, did interpolation and got correction map which I applyed on image. But result still not precise. May be because it hard to get map by interpolation for sparse points.

Could you give me some advises how to solve this task? I think there should be a proven solution for this common task.

Comment: give sample images

Comment: It's private document I want avoid to share it.

Comment: In image processing & computer vision fields solution always relies on the input images and will most likely vary for different objects. Please provide [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & add some samples of what you have and what you expect the result to be. If your object is a private document - find a similar document without private information on it.

Comment: No picture, no answer.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. thanks, will add samples and code tomorrow